# Use ran1 FORTRAN 77 subroutine in FORTRAN 90

Tags: random, fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I am trying to use `ran1` from Numerical Recipes in my FORTRAN 90 code. I think a common way is to compile the old subroutine separately, then use the object file. But here I want to know what change is necessary to use it directly in my code.

```
FUNCTION ran1(idum)
INTEGER idum,IA,IM,IQ,IR,NTAB,NDIV
REAL ran1,AM,EPS,RNMX
PARAMETER (IA=16807,IM=2147483647,AM=1./IM,IQ=127773,IR=2836,
! NTAB=32,NDIV=1+(IM-1)/NTAB,EPS=1.2e-7,RNMX=1.-EPS)
! “Minimal” random number generator of Park and Miller with Bays-Durham shuffle and
! added safeguards. Returns a uniform random deviate between 0.0 and 1.0 (exclusive of
! the endpoint values). Call with idum a negative integer to initialize; thereafter, do not
! alter idum between successive deviates in a sequence. RNMX should approximate the largest
! floating value that is less than 1.
INTEGER j,k,iv(NTAB),iy
SAVE iv,iy
DATA iv /NTAB*0/, iy /0/
iy = 0
if (idum.le.0.or.iy.eq.0) then !Initialize.
idum=max(-idum,1)
! Be sure to prevent idum = 0.
do 11 j=NTAB+8,1,-1
! Load the shuffle table (after 8 warm-ups).
k=idum/IQ
idum=IA*(idum-k*IQ)-IR*k
if (idum.lt.0) idum=idum+IM
if (j.le.NTAB) iv(j)=idum! Compute idum=mod(IA*idum,IM) without overflows by
enddo 11
iy=iv(1)
endif
k=idum/IQ
idum=IA*(idum-k*IQ)-IR*k
! Compute idum=mod(IA*idum,IM) without overflows by
if (idum.lt.0) idum=idum+IM      ! Schrage’s method.
j=1+iy/NDIV
iy=iv(j)                ! Output previously stored value and refill the shuffle table.

iv(j)=idum
ran1=min(AM*iy,RNMX)    ! Because users don’t expect endpoint values.
return
END
```

Comment: You should probably use a more recent [random number generator](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/FORTRAN/fortran.html).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is! You could just put the code inside a module and use it. I do not see any particular features that are not supported in free form...

Comment: Please Talk as you are talking with a 3 year-old child. When I put inside a module I get lots of error like `error #5082: Syntax error, found INTEGER_CONSTANT '11' when expecting one of: <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER>
enddo 11
`

Comment: So, did you find some problem when using it? Any error message? What about numerical recipes in Fortran 90? BTW many people don't like numerical recipes too much. There are many other good random generators available. Honestly, even `random_number()` in gfortran will be probably better.

Comment: Please edit the errors and commands that generated them into your question.

Comment: O.K. so I think it's better to forget about these messy codes.

Comment: Your code does not look like Fortran 77 at all BTW. Are you sure it looks exactly like you pasted it? It looks like Fortran 90 just written in an ugly way.

Comment: It's in Numerical recipes section 7.1 page 271. I think `DATA ` is defined only in 77

Comment: No, it isn't, `DATA` is still allowed even in draft Fortran 2015. And the comments are in Fortran 90 style.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is malformed. It looks like you copied it manually from the book, but not exactly. The second problem is actually present even in the book.

Firstly, there should be a line continuation and not a comment in the parameter statement on the second and third line

```
PARAMETER (IA=16807,IM=2147483647,AM=1./IM,IQ=127773,IR=2836, &
  NTAB=32,NDIV=1+(IM-1)/NTAB,EPS=1.2e-7,RNMX=1.-EPS)
```

(converted to free form, see the book for the original)

Secondly, the loop is a strange combination of a do loop with numeric label and a do loop with `end do`:

```
do 11 j=NTAB+8,1,-1
...
enddo 11
```

should be

```
do j=NTAB+8,1,-1
...
enddo
```

or

```
do 11 j=NTAB+8,1,-1
...
11 continue
```

There may be more problems present.

Comment: that weird numbered 'do/enddo` construct is in "NUMERICAL RECIPES IN FORTRAN 77".  The book also puts comments on the line that are not meant to be copied as part of the code. (no ! in the book comments so they are not valid fixed or free form comments)